# How to properly validate account information from a textfield using a scanner

Tags: validation, javafx

So in this project, My partners and I made a GUI. I need to validate the email and password by checking from a text file named `e.txt`.
[Login GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7iZ4.png)
I just wanted to know if the code below is somewhat sound. Once I tried running it I started running into some errors. Another change I made is I made the textfield ids. We had the textfields there, there just did not have any ids. Now that I've made them ids and saved the changes, the problems have started. The program doesn't allow the gui to pop up anymore since I've saved the changes to the login.fxml. Syntax wise, is there anything wrong with the validateEmailAndPassword function?

```
 package cais240courseproj;

    public class CAIS240CourseProj extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {



//netbeans has directed me to this as the problem that isn't allowing 
      //the program to run
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));

            Scene scene = new Scene(root);

            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
            stage.setResizable(false);
        }

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

    }
```

---

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    boolean validAccount;

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private ImageView iv;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane rootLogin;

    @FXML 
    private Button registerBtn;

    @FXML 
    private Button EmailTextField;

    @FXML 
    private Button passwordTextField;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        label.setText("Hello World!");
    }

    @FXML
    private void loadRegister(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

       Parent registerPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Register.fxml"));

       //Make sure the textfields aren't empty
       if( (!EmailTextField.getText().isEmpty() ) && ( !passwordTextField.getText().isEmpty() ) )

           //take the user input (email and password) and compare them with registered
           //account info
           validatePassAndEmail(EmailTextField.getText(), passwordTextField.getText());   

       Scene tableViewScene = new Scene(registerPane);

       Stage window = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
       window.setScene(tableViewScene);
       window.show();
    }

    private void validatePassAndEmail(String email, String password) throws IOException{   
       boolean sameEmail = false, samePassword = false; 

       Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("e.txt"));

       //comparing and checking to see if the user input is a registered account
       while( (sameEmail == false) && (samePassword == false) ){
           while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
               if( sameEmail == false && email.equals(scan.next()))
                   sameEmail = true;
               if(samePassword == false && password.equals(scan.next()))
                   samePassword = true;

               //if the scanner has reached the end with no matches
               if(scan.next().equals(""))
                   break; 
           }
       }
       if( sameEmail == true && samePassword == true )
           validAccount = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: login.fxml will no longer load after saving the changes made the gui. All i did was add fx ids to the textfields. I updated the `@fxml's` in side the document controller also.

Comment: unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should the `EmailTextField` and `passwordTextField` have type `TextField`?
Button Node does not have method `.getText()`

```
@FXML 
private TextField EmailTextField;

@FXML 
private TextField passwordTextField;
```